# Is Big O notation merit Time Complexity or Rate of Growth?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am studying Data Structures and Algorithms through internet and I learnt that;

- Time complexity is the **amount of time taken by an algorithm to run, as a function of the length of the input**
- Big O notation is **a metric for calculating time complexity**
  and
- Rate of Growth is **the rate at which the cost of the algorithm grows as the size of its input grows.**

Assume there is an algorithm which has a `f(n) = n^2+3n+1` total number of operations.
Then what would be the Time Complexity and Rate of growth if this algorithm?
Are both represent by `O(n^2)`?

It is not clear for me that what is the difference between Time Complexity and Rate of Growth when representing using Big O notation.

Please help me to get a clear idea about the terms. It'll be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think "rate of growth" is a less formal way of saying "complexity", often time complexity. "Time complexity" means runtime (measured in some basic operations) as a function of the size of the input or sometimes just the input, approximated by big O or big Theta.

Comment: The definition `amount of time taken by an algorithm to run` is strictly not true. The Rate of growth is a better definition and sinonimous to Time Complexity. It shows how the execution time would grow / scale from the input size.

Time Complexity / Rate of Growth `big O notation` is of course correlated to the execution time `measured in miliseconds, seconds, etc`, but you can have an algorithm that scales worse (bubble sort - `O(n^2)`) actually execute faster (quicksort `O(n logn)`) on a certain number of elements (say, 4 elements).

Comment: Wouldn't Rate of Growth be a derivative? Like O(1) would have growth rate of 0.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I am not sure as I'm unfamiliar with `rate of growth` term. The definition could be understood as derivative of time complexity, if its the rate at which time complexity itself grows.

But looking at some sources rate of growth seems to be used as synonym to time complexity and denoted as Big O.

Comment: > The rate at which running time increases as a function of input is called Rate of Growth.

Comment: Semantics aside, I have always used `Time Complexity` and have been universally understood, so I would advice to keep on that terminology as well as its intuitive. Just remember that its not the actual execution time (in seconds) but how the execution time SCALES from input size.

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan Agreed. I never once had to find Rate of Growth for any algorithm in any of my CS coursework to talk about Time Complexity. In the derivative sense, perhaps it would be good just to get some cross-connect between CS and Calculus courses, but once one has developed the intuition for it, a derivative or other rate calculation wouldn't be all that productive to compute.

Comment: *Rate of growth* is not an appropriate term, as it rather denotes an increase per unit (sometimes even a relative increase). The *cost* of the algorithm (seen in the definition) is a generic term that denotes some quantity that you consider as a penalty, such as running time or storage space.

Comment: "Big-O notation is a metric for calculating time complexity" is not so correct. The Big-O notation is used to express the asymptotic behavior of *any function* (can be the time complexity, but not only; for instance, log(n!) = O(n log(n)).).

Answer (score 1):

Big O describes *both* the rate of growth and the time complexity. However, as is mentioned in the comments, the former relates as a derivative. As in the case of O(1), the time is constant so there is no dependent growth rate, but the time complexity is still 1.

In your case of an O(n^2) algorithm, the runtime (time complexity) will grow at the expected rate of n^2 (rate of growth).

Also in this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-growth-rate-of-an-algorithm-and-the-running-time-of-an-algorithm) of roughly the same question, the answer states the "runtime depends on the current input size, and the growth rate describes how the runtime will increase as the input size grows."